# Set different pointPadding with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to emphasise the difference between 2 different series in the same graphic : one coming from the user data and one from static data as following :
[image]

I wanted to define the `pointPadding` value, but this is available for all the series. How can I set this value only for a specific serie ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution seems to be adding a second x-axis and separate series. For example:

```
  series: [{
    ...,
    groupPadding: 0.325,
    id: 'id1'
  }, {
    ...,
    groupPadding: 0.325,
    id: 'id2'
  }, {
    ...,
    xAxis: 1,
    linkedTo: 'id1'
  }, {
    ...,
    xAxis: 1,
    linkedTo: 'id2'
  }],
  xAxis: [{
    width: '20%',
    type: 'category',
    tickWidth: 1
  }, {
    offset: 0,
    width: '80%',
    left: '20%',
    type: 'category',
    tickWidth: 1
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rwg6tL2v/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis